# Error Importing Site using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, feature

I'm trying to Import a site using PowerShell via the command `Import-SPWeb`. During the import process I got a fatal error stating

> "Could not find Feature MobilePowerPointViewer".

Since the destination Farm doesn't have Office Web Apps. I deactivated from the source Farm and re-exported the Site. I tried to import it again but now get a fatal error

> "Could not find Feature ExcelServerEdit."

My question is how or where can disable this feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use PowerShell to identify the feature.

```
Get-SPFeature | Where-Object { $_.DisplayName -like "Excel*" }
```

You can disable feature using

```
Disable-SPFeature –identity "ExcelServerEdit" -URL http://webapp
```

Comment: Thanks @Amal-Hashim, this is what I ended up doing and it worked like a charm. So not all features would appear in the site collection features where you can disable or enable them manually?

Comment: It depends on the Site Collection Template, the list of solutions activated on the web application and lot of other factors.

Comment: @AmalHashim I disabled the feature, again export site using power shell and tried to import but still I am getting the same error. I don't know what else to do.